# Apply custom coupon discount code for products in cart

Tags: magento, discount, coupon

I want to create rule with below requirement:

product A --- no special price ---coupon code can be use

product B --- Special price ---coupon code cannot be used

product A + product B -----no DISCOUNT on product A and DISCOUNT on product B ---- coupon is applied to product A ONLY

Please give some hint.

Thanks

Comment: have you find solution for that?if yes then plz share the solution

Answer (score 0):

app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Address\Total

Discount.php 
in

```
  $items = $address->getAllItems();
```

you can get all item and

```
 foreach ($items as $item) {
```

in loop you can check your product condition

after that you can rewrite this model for Discount.php in your extension